# How to include version and author information in Dart Native on windows

Tags: windows, dart, visual-studio-code, exe, author

How do I include version number, author information and other application metadata in a compiled dart native application?

I have included it in the pubspec.yaml file but does not show up when checking the properties of the compiled exe in windows.

I am running dart 2.2 on Windows 10 in VS Code.

Any help would be appreciated.